# Symfony Choice Field - Optgroup removal

Tags: symfony, optgroup

How can I remove the Optgroup inside a choice field? Actually, I use an array like:

```
 [$data looks like :[0]=some value,[1]=someothervalue ....]
    foreach($data as $item){
      $array[] = array($item => $item);
   }

 ->add('data', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array($array),
                'multiple' => false,
            ))
```

When I feed my choice field with this, i get optgroups which I don't want to be displayed because it is confusing and it look like:

```
0
some value
1
someothervalue 
...
```

For the reason that I want to store the Value in database and not the index like 1,2,3,4,5, I need to set it up like this but I am stucking :(

Comment: What do you want to remove? The numbers before the values?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach($data as $item){
    $array[$item] = $item;
}

->add('data', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => $array,
     'multiple' => false,
))
```

Comment: Great, thats what I wanna do. Thx a lot.

Comment: Couple years later I stumble across this, thanks :). 
I did 'choices' => [ $array ], which caused symfony to add the optgroup as it adds an array within an array to the choices. (makes sense that it becomes an optgroup :))